# Partial vim commandline mapping

Tags: vim

In vim, I want to do something like so

```
function! ModuleFile()
  let $module = input("Module of file> ")
  :e **/${module}_
endfunction
map <Leader>e :call ModuleFile()<CR>
```

What I expect is that for example, if I type for the module "ABC", I would get this commandline in vim:

```
:e **/ABC_
```

and then subsequently typing new text, like "name_of_file", would get me:

```
:e **/ABC_name_of_file
```

and finally pressing Enter would execute the command.  The point of this is to be able to get tab completions.

Comment: Uhmm, what is "Module of file" and what is that function supposed to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for sigils in vim script, `${...}` or `$var` is for environment variables.

```
function! ModuleFile()
  let module = input("Module of file> ")
  let name   = input("Search pattern> ")
  execute 'args **/' . module . '_' . name
endfunction
map <Leader>e :call ModuleFile()<CR>
```

After your comment what you want is probably:

```
map <leader>e :args **/<c-r>=input("Module of file: ") . '_' . input("Search pattern: ")<cr>
```

Comment: I want it to leave me at the commmand line.  So after pressing <Leader>e, then for example ABC for module and Graphics for search pattern, and then afterwords typing "abcdefg<CR>", I want the following to execute:

    `:e **/ABC_Graphicsabcdefg`

Comment: @solinent: answered. Should meet your criteria.